# How can I replace embedded styles being applied by VideoJS?

Tags: jquery, css, video.js, content-security-policy

Our website is following a strict Content Security Policy.

```
style-src https: 'nonce-<nonce_value>'
script-src https: 'nonce-<nonce_value>
```

[videojs.js](https://videojs.com/guides/skins/#:%7E:text=A%20%22vjs%2Dstyles%2Ddimensions,important%20to%20overcome%20inline%20styles.) calculates the video player dimensions and appends them into embedded styles such as width and height into a style tag with the class - vjs-styles-dimensions. We need these styles to be applied.

```
<style class="vjs-styles-defaults">
  .video-js {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  .vjs-fluid {
    padding-top: 56.25%
  }
</style>
<style class="vjs-styles-dimensions">
  .<videoId>-dimensions {
    width: 300px;
    height: 168.75px;
  }

  .<videoId>-dimensions.vjs-fluid {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
  }
</style>
```

One way to do this was to add a nonce value to the javascript logic where these styles are created but that would mean we have to alter the library code which is not a good practice.

Could someone please suggest an alternative?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that's what [`style-src-attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src-attr) is for: _"The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) style-src-attr directive specifies valid sources for inline styles applied to individual DOM elements."_ Only caveat: Not implemented in Safari yet.

Comment: Those are _embedded_ styles, not inline.